# Python Bolt Hanging After Emitting Two Tuples

Tags: python, apache-storm

I have a python bolt which parses information from a file. The bolt in question receives a file path, parses the file and then emits a number of tuples from within a for loop.

The problem is that when it runs only two tuples are emitted and then it hangs. In the logs I can see that the correct number of keys have been parsed from the file and the first two tuples have been emitted but after this there are no other logs related to the bolt. (Only metrics logs)

> 38640 [Thread-19] INFO  backtype.storm.task.ShellBolt - ShellLog
> pid:14644, name:ParseFileBolt Number of keys = 1373
>
> 38870 [Thread-21] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.task - Emitting:
> ParseFileBolt default ["177328623"]
>
> 38870 [Thread-21] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.task - Emitting:
> ParseFileBolt default ["177328532"]

Here is a simplified version of the code which produces the issue.
As noted in the code if I manually enter a number of keys instead of parsing them from the file they all get emitted successfully.

```
import gzip
import storm


class ParseFileBolt(storm.BasicBolt):
    def process(self, tup):
        file_path = tup.values[0]
        
        # If I parse keys from a file only two get emitted
        keys = get_keys(file_path)
        # e.g keys = {'393548331', '177329025', '123456789'}
        
        # If I manually enter the keys they all get emitted
        #keys = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
        
        storm.logInfo("Number of keys = {0}".format(len(keys)))
        for key in keys:
            storm.emit([key])

def get_keys(file_name):
    with gzip.open(file_name, 'rt') as file:
        key_set = set()
        for line in file:
            if line.startswith("#"):
                continue
            else:
                columns = line.split("|")
                key = columns[0].strip(' \t\n\r')
                key_set.add(key)
    return key_set

ParseFileBolt().run()
```

The file which is being parsed is a .gz file which contains a header row starting with # followed by rows of '|' separated data.

```
# Header Row
177328623|columns1|column2|column3
177328532|columns1|column2|column3
123456789|columns1|column2|column3
...
```

I'm using apache-storm-0.9.4 on Windows.
The issue occurs on both local and remote clusters.

Any thoughts on what the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what does `keys = get_keys(file_path)` produce? I would guess that the third line in your file produces an invalid key which storm doesn't know what do do with

Comment: **get_keys(file_path)** will return a set of strings
e.g. {'393548331', '177329025', '177328877'}
I've checked the output of **get_keys** and all values in the list are as expected

Comment: I changed from using **storm.emit([key])** to **storm.emitBolt([key])** and this seemed to resolve the issue. Looking at the storm.py file it seems these methods do different things, will need to investigate further to work out exactly why one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: Strange thing... If you don't want to emit directly, storm.emit([key]) should work. If you call storm.emit([key]), ShellBolt emits tuple and writes task id to let subprocess know where to send. Subprocess waits that message to go on, and seems like there's a problem to get task id. Could you add a line ```logInfo(m)``` before ```sendMsgToParent(m)``` from ```emitBolt()``` in storm.py and tell what ShellBolt logs?